# how to return value in self defined type in neo4jclient

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I'm new to neo4jclient and i don't know how to return self defined type in neo4jclient.
i have the following cypher:

```
var result = client.Cypher
                .Match("(u:User)-[:" + FriendRelation + "]->(friend:User)")
                .Return((user, friend) => new RelationInDB(user.As<User>().id, friend.As<User>().id)).Results;
```

i want to return all id pair that have friend relation and i want to store two id in self defined class--RelationInDB, but i don't know how to write Return(i know the return above is wrong)
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are 2 things you'll find which are causing you issues:

1. You can't return into the constructor of a class, you need to use a default constructor and property setting
2. Your return statement has `(user, friend) =>` but your match statement has `(u:User)`. Your return statement should be: `(u, friend) =>`

To that end:

```
 var results = client
      .Cypher
      .Match("(u:User)-[:" + FriendRelation + "]->(friend:User)")
      .Return((u, friend) => new RelationInDB{UserId = u.As<User>().Id, FriendId = friend.As<User>().Id}).Results;
```

My `RelationInDB` class is defined as:

```
public class RelationInDB
{
    public int FriendId { get;  set; }
    public int UserId { get;  set; }

    public RelationInDB() { }
}
```

If you can't change your RelationInDB class and you need to use it as is, you will have to use an anonymous type for your return:

```
 var results = client
      .Cypher
      .Match("(u:User)-[:" + FriendRelation + "]->(friend:User)")
      .Return((u, friend) => new {UserId = u.As<User>().Id, FriendId = friend.As<User>().Id}).Results;
```

and parse afterwards with something like:

```
var relsInDb = results.Select(result => new RelationInDB(result.UserId, result.FriendId));
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I got the data from database.